# DataGridView attempting to save bound data with formatted value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am attempting to format a time value from a mssql database. The value is stored in the database as an int with hhmm as the format(for example: 1900 or 2130) I am unable to edit the database format as it is used by other software as well.

It is automatically bound to the DataGridView, and this has worked perfectly. However the specification I am working to says that it MUST show as a standard time format. So I have used the CellFormatting Event to show the times like 19:00 and 21:30.

It shows the value fine, however when I go to edit this value using the DataGridView it doesn't change it back to the unformatted value so I get the formatted value in the edit box. If I don't remove the colon I get an exception about saying Input is Invalid.

It was my understanding that the formatted value and the true value are not the same and this wouldn't cause an issue.

My code for formatting his below:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)
            return;

        string CellName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
        if (timeFormattedCells.Contains(CellName))
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string currentFormat = e.Value.ToString();

                    if (currentFormat.Length == 3)
                    {
                        currentFormat = "0" + currentFormat;
                    }

                    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(currentFormat, "HHmm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    currentFormat = dateTime.ToShortTimeString();

                    e.Value = currentFormat;

                    e.FormattingApplied = true;
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    e.FormattingApplied = false;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

I also need to ensure that the user cannot put an invalid time like 2405 or 1299.

Does anyone have a suggestion that might help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your CellFormatting event is formatting the way you want, I would probably check the validity of the time first and then convert it to int...I would try something like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        bool valid;
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        // Regex pattern acceptable for a time format
        Regex timeRegex = new Regex("^([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$");

        if (cell.Value == null || cell.Value.ToString() == string.Empty)
        {
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            cell.ToolTipText = string.Empty;
            cell.Tag = "empty";

            valid = false;
        }
        // If the regex does not match then the format is invalid
        else if (!timeRegex.IsMatch(cell.Value.ToString()))
        {
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Beige;
            cell.ToolTipText = "Invalid format.";
            cell.Tag = "invalid";

            valid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            cell.ToolTipText = string.Empty;
            cell.Tag = "valid";

            valid = true;
        }

        if(valid)
        {
            string timeToConvert = cell.Value.ToString();
            string timeConvertReady = timeToConvert.Replace(":", "");
            int timeAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(timeConvertReady);

            updateTimeInDatabase(timeAsInt);
        }
    }
```

updateTimeInDatabase(timeAsInt) would be a method that sends the update command.  This could also be a TableAdpater method or whatever you are using. If it was a TableAdapter the syntax would look something like testTableAdapter.Update(timeAsInt);

Comment: I tired to use the CellEditEnd event, but the true value stays unformatted, the problem is the bound data TableAdapter is using the formatted data for some reason when updating the live database

Comment: @Ashley Williams  Have you tried the code yet?...If not use this code first because this should force the values to be formatted correctly. If you are using the default TableAdapter.Update method and it doesn't work you may want to create a customer TableAdapter.UpdateTime method which will send an update command that you create.  Use the code above and get back to me.

Comment: @Ashley Williams  I checked your code and the e.Value is the cell value whether or not you set the formattingapplied flag to true.